# Casting 2d Array to List of lists in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, multidimensional-array

So, this might be a simple question, but I wasn't able to find any easy or elegant way to do this. Converting an array to a list is trivial in Java

```
Double[] old = new Double[size];
List<Double> cast = Arrays.asList(old);
```

But I'm dealing with images currently and I would like the ability to extend this functionality to a 2d array without having to iterate through one dimension of the array appending to a list.

```
Double[][] -> List<List<Double>>
```

Is basically what I would like to achieve. I have a solution along the lines of:

```
Double[][] old= new Double[width][height];
List<List<Double>> new= new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
for (int i=0;i<old.length();i++){
    new.add(Arrays.asList(old[i]));
}
```

I would like something better and potentially faster than this.

Comment: You have to use nested  for loop .

Comment: You have the solution right there. There is no quicker way really.

Comment: Everybody always wants to avoid loops... Eventually you or some library must to use one.

Comment: Why not mixing both? List<double[]>: no autoboxing ==> better performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only faster way to do this would be with a fancier view; you could do this with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) like so:

```
Double[][] array;
List<List<Double>> list = Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(array),
  new Function<Double[], List<Double>>() {
    @Override public List<Double> apply(Double[] row) {
      return Arrays.asList(row);
    }
  }
}
```

That returns a view in constant time.

Short of that, you already have the best solution.

(FWIW, if you do end up using Guava, you could use `Doubles.asList(double[])` so you could use a primitive `double[][]` instead of a boxed `Double[][]`.)

Answer (score 2):

As Java8 you do `Arrays.stream(array).map(Arrays::asList).collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 0):

After `JAVA 8 stream APIs` we can get the list of lists from 2d array in a much faster and cleaner way.

```
Double[][] old= new Double[width][height];
List<List<Double>> listOfLists = Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(old)).map(row -> {
        return Arrays.asList((row != null) ? row : new Double[0]);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider matrix as your 2d array then

```
List<List<Integer>> resList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int[] rows : matrix) {
resList.add(Arrays.stream(rows).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```